# подуровни выпадающего меню выпадают сразу все

Tags: html, css, haml, ruby-on-rails

Не могу разобраться с выводом подкатегорий в выпадающем меню. сделал только второй уровень (меню -> субменю), но третий и четвертый уровни появляются сразу.

Т.е. имею:
**категория 1** -> **категория 2** -> **категория 3** -> **категория 4**

При наведении на **категория 1** у меня появляются сразу все стальные категории. а должно поочередно: навел на **категорию 1** появилась только **категория 2**, навел на **категория 2** появилась только **категория 3**

```css
.menu {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}
.menu * {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.menu .submenu {
  display: none;
}

.menu ul li {
  padding: 3px 0 3px 25px;
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
}
.menu ul li:hover a {
  color: white;
}
.menu ul li a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.menu ul li a:hover, .menu ul li a:active {
  color: white;
}
.menu ul li:hover .submenu {
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 230px;
  width: 250px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
}

.submenu ul li:hover .submenu {
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 230px;
  width: 250px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
}

.menu ul li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid white;
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
  .menu
    %ul     
      - ProductCategory.where(name: 'Общий каталог').first.children.active.sort_by(&:name).each do |pc|
        = link_to "/catalogs/#{pc.to_param}.html" do
          %li
            = pc.name
            - children = pc.children.active.sort_by(&:name)
            - if children.present?
              .submenu
                %ul
                  - children.sort_by(&:name).each do |child|
                    = link_to "/catalogs/#{child.to_param}.html" do
                      %li= child.name
                      - children_2 = child.children.active.sort_by(&:name)
                      - if children_2.present?
                        .submenu_2
                          %ul
                            - children_2.sort_by(&:name).each do |child_2|
                              = link_to "/catalogs/#{child_2.to_param}.html" do
                                %li= child_2.name
                                - children_3 = child_2.children.active.sort_by(&:name)
                                - if children_3.present?
                                  .submenu_3
                                    %ul
                                      - children_3.sort_by(&:name).each do |child_3|
                                        = link_to "/catalogs/#{child_3.to_param}.html" do
                                          %li= child_3.name
```

Прошу помощи в правильной организации кода, как в haml так и css.  Как организовать .submenu_2 и .submenu_3?

Comment: "не совсем понимаю какая верстка получается на выходе" - можно ведь закинуть в песочницу и посмотреть на сгенерированный html.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду в инспекторе посмотреть?

Comment: Вообще в хамле вроде бы ожидаемая верстка)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать вместо такого селектора

```
.menu ul li:hover .submenu {
```

вариант с `>`

```
.menu ul li:hover > .submenu {
```

Разница в том, что если первый селектор выбирает все `.submenu` внутри  `li:hover`, второй селектор выбирает только прямого потомка (1 уровень вложенности)

`.submenu_1`, `.submenu_2` и тд переименуйте в `.submenu` в этом случае

Comment: Перестал отображать третий уровень, но в инспекторе смотрю html вроде все правильно.

Comment: Теперь, возможно, нужно задать для `.submenu` параметры какие-то? чтобы при наведении на `.submenu` был `display: block` например